# Default element value is used instead of user defined in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point, printf, conversion-specifier

I am beginner in C. I have been writing a program code to find largest element in Array.
Passed Value is not able to store in array of type: float.
Instead default Value:0 is being stored.
What to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Largest Element

int main() {
    int n,i;
    float arr[100];

    printf("Enter Element Count in range(1,100):-");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while(n>100 || n<1){
        printf("Enter Element Count in range(1,100) again:-");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter Element:-");
        scanf("%f",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        printf("Element-%d:-%d\n",k+1,arr[k]);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        
        for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
            
            if (arr[j] < arr[k]){
                break;
            }
            else{
                printf("Largest Element:-%d\n",arr[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
        continue;   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[OUTPUT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZBGA.png)

Comment: You need to use `%f` when printing the array value, not `%d`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. One More Doubt Occurred, Still I am not able to have desired output. Largest Element is still not printing. Where I am going wrong for it?

My Line of Thinking:- I am comparing first element to rest. If it is largest then print it. If not then comparison of next to rest all.

Comment: @RACHITMITTAL the logic of your code is not 100% correct for what your initial goal is.

Comment: after the printing issues are fixed, your algorithm to find the max [isn't working](https://godbolt.org/z/71afz56nx) I'm afraid. No need for the double `for` loop, just do something like `float max = arr[0]; for(j=1; j<n; j++) if (arr[j] > max) max = arr[j];`

Comment: Please always copy&paste the output as formatted text directly into the question instead of showing screenshots of plain text.

Comment: RACHIT MITTAL, Good compilers with warnings fully enabled will warn about `scanf("%f",&arr[i]);`.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output values of the type `float` you have to use the conversion specifier `f`. The conversion specifier `d` is designed to output integer values.

So these calls of printf

```
printf("Element-%d:-%d\n",k+1,arr[k]);
```

and

```
printf("Largest Element:-%d\n",arr[j]);
```

are incorrect. You have to write

```
printf("Element-%d:-%f\n",k+1,arr[k]);
```

and

```
printf("Largest Element:-%f\n",arr[j]);
```

Also if you are going to find the largest element in the array then these for loops do not make a sense.

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    
    for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
        
        if (arr[j] < arr[k]){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Largest Element:-%d\n",arr[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
    continue;   
}
```

At least for example the `continue` statement is redundant. And the inner for loop is also redundant because it is interrupted at once due to `break` statements in the if-else statement.

The largest element is searched the following way using only one for loop.

```
int largest = 0;

for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( arr[largest] < arr[i] ) largest = i;
}

printf( "Largest Element:-%f at position %d\n",arr[largest], largest );
```

Comment: @stark Your advice does not make a sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation**
In the two cases below you are using `%d` to print a float number. That's why you are getting `0` printed and not the actual number.

Use `%f` like you did for reading the value on `scanf` earlier instead of `%d` for the float values.

```c
printf("Element-%d:-%d\n",k+1,arr[k]);
```

```c
printf("Largest Element:-%d\n",arr[j]);
```

Comment: Thanks for Doubt Clearance, Sir.